# profiling and performance issues

Tags: c++, profiling

After observing some performance issues in my program, I decided to run a profiling session. The results seem to indicate that something like 87% of samples taken were somehow related to my `Update()` function.

In this function, I am going through a list of `A*`, where `sizeof(A)` equals 72, and deleting them after processing.

```
void Update()
{
//...

    for(auto i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++)
    {
        A* pA = *i;
        //Process item before deleting it.
        delete pA;
    }

     myList.clear();

//...
}
```

where myList is a `std::list<A*>`. On average, I am calling this function anywhere from 30 to 60 times per second while the list contains an average of 5 items. That means I'm deleting anywhere from 150 to 300 `A` objects per second.

Would calling delete this many times be enough to cause a performance issue in most cases? Is there any way to track down exactly where in the function the problem is occuring? Is delete generally considered an expensive operation?

Comment: What does the destructor of `A` do?  There are lots of things that can cause "performance problems".  For instance, try using a `std::vector` instead of a `std::list`, cache locality alone can have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: I have not defined a destructor, only a constructor. I will try replacing the list with a vector and see if it helps.

Comment: Another problem is all of those little `A` objects lying around, particularly when used in conjunction with lists (and possibly with other allocations). Your memory is going to be fractured and dispersed. You might want to think of making a custom allocator for allocating those `A` objects, allocating from and restoring to a contiguous pool of unused `A` objects.

Comment: As @DavidHammen suggests (and I alluded to above), memory fragmentation can be a major pain point for performance.  If you try with a `std::vector`, can you also avoid storing pointers?  So, `std::vector<A*>` becomes `std::vector<A>`?  Generally the only reason _not_ to do this would be to have polymorphic behavior, and in that case you should look to employ some memory pooling mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My `A` class does have a virtual function that I depend on but I will have have to look into memory pooling. It's also possible that my issue is somewhere else entirely in Update() but the profiler doesn't give me any more information and I just wanted to rule out all those `delete`s first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult to tell, since you brush over what is probably the bulk of the work done in the loop and give no hint as to what A is...

If A is a simple collection of data, particularly primitives then the deletion is almost certainly not the culprit. You can test the theory by splitting your update function in two - update and uninit. Update does all the processing, uninit deletes the object and clears the list.

If only update is slow, then it's the processing. If only uninit is slow, then it's the deletion. If both are slow then memory fragmentation is probably the culprit.

As others have pointed out in the comments, std::vector may give you a performance increase. But be careful since it may also cause performance problems elsewhere depending on how you build the data structure.

Comment: `A` is made up almost entirely of primitive types. I'm thinking that `delete` might not be the problem after reading your answer. Good advice to split up into different functions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [tcmalloc](http://gperftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tcmalloc.html) from [gperftools](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) (Google Performance Tools). gperftools also contains a profiler (both libraries only need to be linked in, very easy). tcmalloc keeps a memory pool for small objects and re-uses this memory when possible.
The profiler can be used for cpu and heap profiling.

Answer (score 0):

**Totally easy to tell what's going on.**

Do yourself a favor and use [*this method*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).
It's been analyzed to the nth degree, and is very effective.

In a nutshell, if 87% of time is in `Update`, then if you just stop it a few times with Ctrl-C or whatever, the probability is 87% each time that you will catch it in the act.

You will not only see that it's in `Update`. You will see *where* in `Update`, and *what* it's doing. If it is in the process of `delete`, or accessing the data structure, you will see that. You will also see, further down the stack, the reason why that operation takes time.